# optimize this code so that it code run in less than 1s

Tags: c, performance, optimization

I have written this c program. This is working well. I want that for very large values like 1000000. This should run in less than 1s.

This program generates a sequence for n>1 . a[0]=a[1]=0 and a[n]=a[n-1]+f(n), where f(n) is the least prime factor of n.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fn(long no)
{
    long i;
    for (i = 2; i <= no; i++)
    {
        if (no % i==0)
        {
            return i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int t,i;
    long n,a1,j;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        a1=0;
        scanf("%ld",&n);
        for(j=2;j<=n;j++)
        {
            a1 = a1 + fn(j);

        }
     printf("%d\n",a1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it run in less than 1 second ? How long does it take right now, since it will be different on another machine ?

Comment: it is taking more than 2s for n=100000.

Comment: Do you have compiler optimisations enabled ?

Comment: actually this is a question on spoj, and it is showing time limit exceeded.

Comment: You should iterate only through primes, not through all integers - build a table of primes first, then use that.

Comment: Could someone help me in reducing these many loops?

Comment: You should have said that it is a SPOJ question in the first place, and you should have given the URL. Also, there are many web pages giving solutions to this kind of problems. Frankly, did you really google it ?

Comment: Your program runs under 1 second on my pc.

Comment: BJobnih - for n=1000000 ?

Zoyd- No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see a big difference just by modifying as follows:

```
#include<math.h>

int fn(long no)
{
    long i;
    int sqrtno= (int)sqrt((double)no);
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrtno; i++)
    {
        if (no % i==0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return no;
}
```

There is no need to continue the search for divisors when you have reached the square root of `no`, because when a divisor is larger than this, the other is smaller.

Comment: I have tried but this is not giving me the required answer.

Comment: See my answer, you have a function with undefined return in the default case (loop ends without finding any answer)

Comment: Quite right. This makes a difference when `no` is a prime. I am posting updated code, now checked. I am surprised the compiler didn't warn me...

Comment: Thank you it works but it is not working for 10000000. Taking huge amount of time.

Comment: Don't use it for such high values, you need more efficient methods. How much effort can you invest in this research ?

Answer (score 0):

This program finds the sum of the smallest prime factor in the range [2, n].

You can set up an int array of n elements, initialize it to 0. Then, use the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to mark off multiples of each prime number. When a number i is a multiple of a prime x, check if it has been marked off, if not, store x into the element[i].

Then, sum all the numbers in the array.

Comment: Yes, I'll see to it . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it nearly fast enough, but not quite, remember that primes can only be numbers ending with 1,3,7,9. So j can go up in 2's and not fall fn if it ends in 5. That should give you a 60% boost straight away.

Comment: 49 is not prime, 21 is not prime, 63 is not prime :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loop:

```
for (i = 2; i <= no; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 2; i * i <= no; i++)
```

Then you remove the break after the return, and add:

```
return no;
```

at the end of the function, after the loop has completed.

**Explanation:**
You don't need to check all possible factors between 2 and n. If you can't find any factor between 2 and sqrt(n), then n is a prime and it's the number you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you it works but it is not working for 10000000. Taking huge amount of time.

Comment: and using sqrt() is lil faster.